# wget seems to quit suddenly?

Tags: bash, hadoop, wget, put

I have written up a small bash script that has, essentially, 2 parts.
Part 1: wget
Part 2: hadoop put

**Part 1**

```
wget -r -nH –cut-dirs=1 -R index.html -P /home/snoiniM/data/in/ https://www.someWebSite.com/folder/level2 --user=someUserName --password=P@ssword
```

The files downloaded are saved to /home/snoiniM/data/in/. Immediately after it's done downloading files, I'd tell it to load all files from /home/snoiniM/data/in/ to /place/in/hadoop/downloaded/

```
hadoop fs -put /home/snoiniM/data/in/ /place/in/hadoop/downloaded/
```

The problem is, the script does the wget part, but does not do the hadoop put part. However, when I comment out the wget line (nothing else change), it ran the hadoop -put part without errors.

Why can't both parts work together? I can't seem to figure out why. Does anyone know?

As requested, here is my actual code.

### Code snippet

```
#! /bin/bash

temp_dir=/tmp/snoiniM
paypal_date=2013-07-01
hdfsdir=/warehouse/hive/f_paypal_agg #target destination

Log INFO "Downloading Paypal Data..."
wget -r -nH -nd -R index.html -A *$paypal_date.zip -P $temp_dir/paypal https://secure.paypaldata.com/gru/ --user=$paypal_user --password=$paypal_passwd

echo "I'll sleep for 2 seconds. Meanwhile, when you see this you know wget is done."
sleep 2
echo "All done. Proceed to hadoop part"

Log INFO "Clearing down any old/duplicate files or data in HDFS..."
for file in /tmp/snoiniM/paypal/*.zip
        do
#               hadoop fs -rm -f /warehouse/hive/f_paypal_agg/${file##*/}
                hadoop fs -rm -f /warehouse/hive/f_paypal_agg/paypal/${file##*/}
done

Log INFO "Loading all trackpal export zip files to HDFS..."
hadoop fs -put $temp_dir/paypal/ $hdfsdir
Log INFO "------------------------------------------------------------"
Log INFO "Paypal exports for $paypal_date loaded to HDFS."

rm -f $temp_dir/paypal/*$paypal_date.zip
Log INFO "Contents in $temp_dir/paypal cleaned and is ready for next run."
```

A quick recap: the program runs without errors, but it stops right after wget -- I don't get to see the sleep message. However, if I then comment out wget and run it for the 2nd time, it does sleep part and then on to hadoop put.

Comment: Does your script use `set -e`, which exits the script if there's an error?

Comment: Why can't you use file systems copy/move?

Comment: No, my script does not have the set -e

Comment: @mirkobrankovic Err, copy/move to where? I can't do that perhaps because I want to put the files on hadoop FS?

Comment: Can you paste your actual script? Maybe you have a spurious `exec` in front of wget that you didn't mention.

Comment: Debug your script with `set -x`?